# rest service that can be accessed by another item like id

Tags: rest, grails

I have a restservice running by exposing a simple domain class. I can acces by

```
http://localhost:8080/Bic/bic/17.json
```

and I get:

{"class":"org.strotmann.bic.BankIdentCode","id":17,"bankname":"ABK-Kreditbank","bic":"ABKBDEB1XXX","blz":10030400,"ort":"Berlin","plz":10115}

I want to acces by something like blz=10030400 or any other item of the domain class except the id.

How to ?

peter
Dortmund, Germany

Answer (score 0):

the controller action code (you should have posted here!) can look like:

```
def bic(){
  def entry = params.find{ k, v -> Bic.metaClass.hasMetaProperty k }
  if( entry ) 
    render( Bic.withCriteria( uniqueResult:true ){ eq entry.key, entry.value } as JSON )
  else
    render text:'not found!`
}
```

Comment: `package org.strotmann.bic
import grails.rest.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject

class BankIdentCodeController extends RestfulController {
 
 static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
 BankIdentCodeController() {
  super(BankIdentCode)
 }
  
 def bic(){
  def entry = params.find{ k, v -> Bic.metaClass.hasMetaProperty k }
  if( entry )
    render( Bic.withCriteria( uniqueResult:true ){ eq entry.key, entry.value } as JSONObject )
  else
    render text:'not found!'
   }
}`

Comment: sorry I don't know how to format. Using the obove controllercode and entering http://localhost:8080/Bic/bic in the browser I getThe requested resource is not available.

Comment: you should be entering `localhost:8080/bankIdentCode/bic?bic=333` if you use default url-mapping

Comment: Hi,thanks so far, it is working fine now except JSON formatting. The as JSON clause is not accepted by the compiler(no class JSON) Could you please tell me which package to import. I tried JSONObject from org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json package, but that does not work either.